# R how to read or replace Spanish special characters

Tags: r

I want to use data from the data set [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/GNFVTT/UND0Z4&version=2.1). It is from a data set in Spanish, from Peru I think. It can be downloaded in several formats but they all seem to have the same problem. Here's an example of the problem - `maÌ_z`. This should be `maíz`. My first thought was that there a font encoding problem. But I have tried several font encoding choices that are sometimes used for Spanish language documents (e.g., UTF-8, WINDOWS-1252, ISO-8859-1) using the RStudio `Reopen with Encoding` option. The character representation changes for some of them but not to the appropriate `í`. Some other examples 
`Cimarr?_n`, `c??scara`, `m??shka`. I think I can do a search and replace but would prefer to find an encoding fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use directly the `encoding` argument in the `read()` function? Here is an example :

```
dt <- read.csv("dt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".",
                     comment.char = "", strip.white = TRUE,
                     stringsAsFactors = TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
```

When I use french data I have to do it this way.

It is possible the orignal file was not encoded in UTF-8, so you may have too encode it before reading it.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: @JerryHave you try to save the file with the "UTF-8" encoding in Notepad++?

Comment: I'm on a mac so don't have Notepad++ but I do have bbedit. I eventually found a place that says the encoding is Western (Mac OS Roman). I tried read.csv with encoding = "Western (Mac OS Roman)". This gives me `Ma<ed>_z`, `Cimarr<ed>_n`, and `c<ed><e7>scara`

Comment: So it still doesn't work. I wonder why it works for my data but not your. Edit : I also get things like ``Agriäó_o`` and ``raäó»z`` with your data.

Comment: Some random ideas. (1) Did you try `read.csv` with `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"` ? (2) Possibly convert the encoding via the program `iconv`. You might have to install `iconv` via Homebrew or something like that. (3) Possibly dump out a small part of the text via `od` (maybe `od -b` to get bytes) and post that so that others can see directly what the file contains. Again you might have to install `od` via Homebrew or some other means. Sorry I can't be more helpful, these are just some ideas.

Comment: @RobertDodier I have tried ``encoding = "ISO-8859-1"``, still some of OP's characters appear strange.

Comment: @JerryN I see that the data are published in RData format as well as csv. Can you import the RData file into your R session? Perhaps whatever encoding issue there is was resolved somehow in order to create the RData file.

Comment: I looked at the csv file, and it appears a lot of accented characters are followed by underscores in the data file itself. My guess is that the file got messed up when it was exported from whatever native format was used to compose it, and therefore it looks to me that it would be necessary to fix up the file (not just change the encoding). Maybe one can find the original native format and go from there.

Comment: It is possible. Altough like OP said it would have been easier to simply change the encoding instead of "editing" the data.

Comment: I loaded the RData file. Still the same problem. I'm now trying od